# High altitude platform: inter-platform link regulation?

Tags: communication

Does anyone know if ITU has a recommendation for HAP-HAP *(High altitude platform-High altitude platform)* or LAP-LAP * or HAP-LAP links recommendation as for inter-satellite links with frequency, latency and etc.??

[Some](https://www.itu.int/en/mediacentre/backgrounders/Pages/High-altitude-platform-systems.aspx) [ITU-R](https://www.itu.int/en/mediacentre/backgrounders/Pages/itu-r-managing-the-radio-frequency-spectrum-for-the-world.aspx) [studies](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/293031852_Broad_band_from_heaven) estimated that the total spectrum needs for HAPS systems lie in the range from 396 MHz to 2 969 MHz for the ground-to-HAPS platform links and in the range from 324 MHz to 1 505 MHz for the HAPS-platform-to-ground links.

[image: from here 3: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/293031852_Broad_band_from_heaven]

In all Documents I found I can not fins inter-platform link frequency band

1. **LAP** - *Low altitude platform*
2. **HAP** - *High altitude platform*

Comment: thanks for the edits!